# Generate RSA key in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, ssh, openssh

Whenever I create a public/private keypair using `ssh-keygen` in Ubuntu 20.04, I get an OpenSSH private key file instead. Even if I manually specify that I want to use rsa using the following command:

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa
```

I still get the following for the `id_rsa` private key file:

```
-----BEGIN OPENSSH PRIVATE KEY-----
...KEY...
-----END OPENSSH PRIVATE KEY-----
```

Why does it say `OPENSSH` instead of `RSA` and does that matter?

It seems to only be an issue with Ubuntu 20.04.

Comment: You asked for an RSA key and got one. What seems to be the problem?

Comment: Why does it say `OPENSSH` instead of `RSA` and does that matter?

Comment: Read `man ssh-keygen`

Comment: It's an RSA key in the OpenSSH V2 format. It might matter for the application you're going to use it with. If it's just OpenSSH, then it won't be a problem